# Parsing Lists with Gooey

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code

```
import argparse
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser


def get_args():
    """Get CLI arguments and options"""
    parser = GooeyParser(description='error test' ,
                         formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('--input', help='List of values',
                        default=['a', 'b', 'c'])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


@Gooey()
def main():

    args = get_args()

    l = args.input

    for count, each in enumerate(l):
        print each

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unfortunately it returns:

```
[
'
a
'
,

'
b
'
,

'
c
'
]
```

If I use the same code but comment out the `@Gooey` decorator, I get :

```
a
b
c
```

If I do the following :

```
import argparse
import ast
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser


def get_args():
    """Get CLI arguments and options"""
    parser = GooeyParser(description='error test' ,
                         formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('--input', help='List of values',
                        default=['a', 'b', 'c'])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


@Gooey()
def main():

    args = get_args()

    l = ast.literal_eval(args.input)

    for count, each in enumerate(l):
        print each

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It returns:

```
a
b
c
```

but using that same code and commenting out the `@Gooey` decorator produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/alex/Source/AT_analyzer/test.py", line 30, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/alex/Source/AT_analyzer/test.py", line 24, in main
l = ast.literal_eval(args.input)
File "/Users/alex/anaconda3/envs/at_analyzer_env/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
return _convert(node_or_string)
File "/Users/alex/anaconda3/envs/at_analyzer_env/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

I'd like to be able to use the same code with and without `Gooey`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relates to the data type returned in `results.input`.

The following code uses Gooey and the result is `<type 'str'>`

```
import argparse
import ast
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser


def get_args():
    """Get CLI arguments and options"""
    parser = GooeyParser(description='error test',
                         formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('--input', help='List of values',
                        default=['a', 'b', 'c'])

    results = parser.parse_args()

    return results


@Gooey()
def main():

    results = get_args()
    print(type(results.input))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Simply commenting the `@Gooey` decorator causes the data type of results.input to change to `<type 'list'>`

The following works with using the `@Gooey` decorator and when it's commented out.

```
import argparse
import ast
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser


def get_args():
    """Get CLI arguments and options"""
    parser = GooeyParser(description='error test',
                         formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('--input', help='List of values',
                        default=['a', 'b', 'c'])

    results = parser.parse_args()

    return results


@Gooey()
def main():

    results = get_args()

    l = ast.literal_eval(str(results.input))

    for count, each in enumerate(l):
        print each

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works because regardless of whether results.input is returned as a list or string, it's explicitly converted to a string then evaluated as a list using `ast.literal_eval`